# How can I put together a portfolio for software inaccessible to the public?

Tags: job-search, portfolio

The company I work for writes a software product that is used by other businesses rather than the general public. In order to log into the web app, a paid account with multiple users is required. It's nothing secret, there's just nothing free that Joe Schmoe can sign up for and take a look at, nor is there a public demo account they could try out.

I need to put together a portfolio of work I've done to use when applying to other jobs. What can I put in my portfolio which won't get me in trouble with my current employer and will showcase my programming and software design skills?

- Can I include sections of code I've written or improved?
- Should I include screenshots of web pages I've worked on?
- Can I included rendered html of web pages I've worked on?
- What sort of things should I try to include in a programming portfolio in general?

I'm interested both in what I can safely include without asking permission, and what I ought to include if I'm able and allowed to.

Comment: Everything you are trying to show sounds like it's covered by non-disclosure and commercial-in-confidence and you would be unlikely to be able to show any of that publicly.  If you want to build a portfolio then you're better off doing something separate on Github.  Honestly though, I've never bothered with having an online portfolio.

Comment: Either your work product is protected or not.  That is not a question for this site.

Comment: Personal portfolio website, with password if  you prefer (that you could give to recruiters/company). Many options possible with the password. Other option is private github repo's. You can manage github users so you can give someone access, and revoke that access later if you like.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts - OK, password protection prevents the current employer from seeing something they may not want the OP posting, but what would a potential employer think about seeing content there that's normally considered confidential?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless you are a web designer and prospective employers want to see samples of your design ability, you aren't likely to be asked for code samples or a portfolio of web pages.  I've been to a lot of interviews and although often the better interviews ask you to write code for them on the spot, they don't ask about what you've already done except in general terms.  They're interested in whether you know *how* to code, not in what use that knowledge was put to in the past.

You might want to bring samples of your code (if you think it will impress) but make it code that you wrote on your own time.  If you bring in samples of code that you've done for other companies that may red-flag you as someone who can't be trusted with proprietary information.  Don't take that chance.

Answer (score 0):

Screen shots and page captures are certainly suitable for a portfolio, even for programmers who do not work on graphics or user interfaces.  As visual aids, they make for great conversation items during an interview.

Even in non-accessible software or sites, developers often have their own accounts for testing purposes, so screen shots of those would do fine.  Just be sure you have the right permission to use them.  Sometimes you can take the graphics from marketing material on the company's site.

I don't know if I'd bother with code samples *in a portfolio*.  An interviewer asking for code samples would probably want something more than a carefully selected page of code.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm coming from another post where the subject is about [my work is private in github.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115375/how-can-i-build-reputation-online-as-a-programmer-when-my-work-is-private)*

I'm ok with what @Francine DeGrood Taylor said, however they can see your activity.

Github offer you a way to show number of private commits you have made so far. Go to **Settings** -> **Contributions** and check **Include private contributions in my profile**.

In that way, people can see "X contributions in private repositories".