# What to show to future employer as portfolio if my previous works are confidential?

Tags: new-job, contracts, projects, portfolio, side-project

I'm a UX designer and I work on several enterprise level applications at my current job, but I don't have clearance to share any detail about them. Nobody has. Although the applications are available publicly behind pay-wall/trial-wall, the employers don't want employees to showcase those in their portfolios. On the other hand, all the new jobs I have applied to are keen on seeing "real-world" projects. What I can show them as my portfolio (because I can't show the things I work on)?

Comment: "What I can show them as my portfolio (because I can't show the things I work on)?" Why not your previous work?

Comment: Have you asked them specifically about this, or the possibility of altering the work so it is clearly not associated with your employers?

Comment: If available publicly, the public parts can't be under NDA. I assume they don't want you putting them in your portfolio b/c it's the companies work not yours...  So there is a clear issue if you use it for a public portfolio to advertise your own services.... However, I doubt there would be a problem with you using them in a private portfolio that you only share with a future employer to get past an interview. - It's basically what everyone does, and not like your current employer will ever find out.

Comment: I recall that this question has already been asked before... will attempt to look for it when I get some spare time

Comment: @flexi Regardless of NDA status, the applications are work-for-hire, and the company maintains ownership and copyright. It's unlikely that the company would find out, but I wouldn't suggest the OP take that risk. It's a small world.

Comment: Done, found it faster than I expected :) I would specifically direct you to this answer: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/115393/73791 which is exactly about UX/UI experience and projects showcasing. The rest of the answers can also be extrapolated and the things there suggested considered and be useful. Good luck

Comment: you can also discuss this extensively on the excellent UX site, enjoy

Comment: @Fattie They sent me here 